# Add arguments to mysql in Django's "dbshell"

Tags: mysql, django, command-line

I'd like to add a couple of command-line arguments to my Django's `./manage.py dbshell` command, and I can't figure out how.

In specific I'd like to add `-A` to prevent MySQL from scanning every table and every column, and `--prompt=LOCAL:` since I frequently keep multiple shells open.

I can't figure out how to do this! I'm only idea is to create my own "mysql" command in /usr/local/bin and have it be a wrapper for mysql with my own flags. But I'd really like to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no direct way to do this.

You need to modify the code `django/db/backends/mysql/client.py`. Don't worry, it is eay.

Comment: this reads more like a comment, see [answer]

Comment: "No, it cannot be done" is very much an answer. And it even explains how to achieve it. Upvoted.